# Docker out of space with vfs driver

Tags: docker, vfs

I'm trying to run an image of wordpress in docker 1.6.2 with kernel 2.6.32-042stab106.4, I'm tight on that kernel because docker is installed in a VPS.

When Docker tries to download the image the system ran out of space.

I tried to change the driver the storage driver to device mapper but then the docker daemon does not start.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you periodically clean up old images/containers to free up space:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Delete all containers
sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
# Delete all images
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -q)
```